# How to we Separate unit of measure in below Json payload

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have tried many scripts to separate below json payload **downloadSpeed** value alone as Number and unit of measure as separate attribute(like **umo**) ,

In **productCharacters**[] array when name as "**downloadSpeed**" then **value**[] array value attribute want to change as **Number** and unit of value have to add as additional attribute(**umo**)

Can some one help to write script for below requirement?.

**json payload**

--

```
{

 "status": "Success",

 "offers": [

  {

   "id": 100,

   "name": "Test1",

   "productCharacters": [

    {

     "name": "downloadSpeed",

     "priority": 1,

     "value": [

      {

       "value": "2000 mpbs",

       "localValue": "300 mbps"

      }

     ]

    },

    {

     "name": "uploadSpeed",

     "priority": 2,

     "value": [

      {

       "value": "1000 mpbs",

       "localValue": "200 mbps"

      }

     ]

    },

    {

     "name": "highlights",

     "priority": 3

    }

   ],

   "category": [

    {

     "name": "INTERNET",

     "priority": 1

    }

   ]

  },

  {

   "id": 200,

   "name": "Test2",

   "productCharacters": [

    {

     "name": "downloadSpeed",

     "priority": 1,

     "value": [

      {

       "value": "2000 mpbs",

       "localValue": "300 mbps"

      }

     ]

    },

    {

     "name": "uploadSpeed",

     "priority": 2,

     "value": [

      {

       "value": "4000 mpbs",

       "localValue": "500 mbps"

      }

     ]

    },

    {

     "name": "benefits",

     "priority": 3

    }

   ]

  }

 ]

}
```

**Expected Result**

--

```
{

 "status": "Success",

 "offers": [

  {

   "id": 100,

   "name": "Test1",

   "productCharacters": [

    {

     "name": "downloadSpeed",

     "priority": 1,

     "value": [

      {

       "value": 2000,

"umo" : "mbps",

       "localValue": "300 mbps"

      }

     ]

    },

    {

     "name": "uploadSpeed",

     "priority": 2,

     "value": [

      {

       "value": "1000 mpbs",

       "localValue": "200 mbps"

      }

     ]

    },

    {

     "name": "highlights",

     "priority": 3

    }

   ],

   "category": [

    {

     "name": "INTERNET",

     "priority": 1

    }

   ]

  },

  {

   "id": 200,

   "name": "Test2",

   "productCharacters": [

    {

     "name": "downloadSpeed",

     "priority": 1,

     "value": [

      {

        "value": 2000,

"umo" : "mbps",

       "localValue": "300 mbps"

      }

     ]

    },

    {

     "name": "uploadSpeed",

     "priority": 2,

     "value": [

      {

       "value": "4000 mpbs",

       "localValue": "500 mbps"

      }

     ]

    },

    {

     "name": "benefits",

     "priority": 3

    }

   ]

  }

 ]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[update](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-operators#update-operator) operator is used to update the payload.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
    case offers at .offers -> offers map ((offer) -> 
        offer update {
            case pcs at .productCharacters -> pcs map ((pc) -> 
                pc update {
                    case value at .value -> value map ((val) ->
                        if (pc.name == 'downloadSpeed')
                            (do {
                                var tmpVal = val.value splitBy " "
                                ---
                                {
                                    value: tmpVal[0] as Number,
                                    umo: tmpVal[1],
                                }
                            }) ++ (val - "value")
                        else val
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are updating Arrays you can use the [`update`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-values-functions-update) function from `dw::util::Values` that handles array updates and lets you avoid extra map and update methods

```js
%dw 2.0
import update from dw::util::Values
output application/json  

fun updateSpeedValuesWithUmo(speedValues: Array) =
  speedValues map ($ dw::core::Objects::mergeWith ({
    value: ($.value splitBy ' ')[0],
    umo: ($.value splitBy ' ')[1]
  }))
---
payload update ['offers', 'productCharacters'] with 
    ($ map (productCharacter) -> productCharacter update 'value' with 
        if (productCharacter.name == 'downloadSpeed') updateSpeedValuesWithUmo($)
        else $)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    %dw 2.0
output application/json
 ---
{
  status: payload.status,
  offers: payload.offers map (
    $  mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
      if((key) as String == "productCharacters") 
      productCharacters: $.productCharacters map ((pc, index) -> 
        pc mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
          if(pc.name == "downloadSpeed" and (key as String)=="value") (key): value map(
            {
              "value": ($.value scan '\d+')[0][0] as Number,
              "umo" : trim(($.value scan '\D+')[0][0]),
             "localValue": $.localValue
            }
          ) else 
          (key) :value
 
        )
      )  else 
        (key): value
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).